# Postfix: processing incoming mail for virtual user

Tags: email, dovecot, filter, aliases

[This discussion on Dovecot ML](https://dovecot.org/pipermail/dovecot/2017-February/107094.html) suggests to use for filtering mail for `foo` user `foo: | /path/to/the/external/program` in `/etc/aliases`. But aliases work only for local user. How to filter with script mail for virtual user (`virtual_alias_maps`)?

Do I have to use [Sieve scripts](http://sieve.info/) or is there anything else for [Dovecot](https://dovecot.org/)? I guess creating real user just to solve this isn't recommended, but maybe I'm wrong (what are

UPDATE:

1. Can you list pros and cons for both solutions (Sieve vs. real user)? I guess security concernt (virtual users are safer).
2. Can you suggest how to implement this with sieve scripts?

Comment: Sounds like you are seeing downsides to both solutions. Unless you mention them in your question, its difficult to provide a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one sensible answer is "procmail"

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79046/extracting-attachments-from-mail-that-is-coming-to-my-postfix-inbox

Have fun.